# Retrieve JSON data from remote URL via jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cross-domain

I am using following code to get the data from URL.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://183.77.251.173:90/api/function/getprice.aspx?code=1301&length=3M',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.results[0].address_components[0].long_name);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        alert(jqXHR.status);
    }
```

However it throws an error with status code of `0`. I don't know what the reason is for this? I tried to set `crossDomian:true` also but it still throws same error.

I also modified the URL to `http://www.google.com` which also returns the error status code of `0`. Why? What is the reason? What is the correct way to get the data from a remote URL?

Comment: _"i tried to set 'crossDomian:true'"_ - Was that misspelling just in the question?

Comment: never heard about Same Origin Policy? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @nnnnnn even if it was, `crossDomain` is only to set a non-crossdomain request as crossdomain. It cannot be used the other way around.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make a cross domain request unless you're using JSONP or CORS. The availability of those will depend on the API of the domain you are requesting information from.

This is a security feature of modern browsers known as the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: How can I know the availability?

Comment: You need to check the documentation of the API you're using to find out what format they return data in.

Answer (score 0):

Look up JSON with padding (or JSONP), since you use jQuery, you should take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Stolen example from that site:

```
<script>
(function() {
  var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
  $.getJSON( flickerAPI, {
    tags: "mount rainier",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  })
  .done(function( data ) {
    $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
      $( "<img/>" ).attr( "src", item.media.m ).appendTo( "#images" );
      if ( i === 3 ) {
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
})();
</script>
```

EDIT:

An homemade example, using jquery.jsonp-2.4.0 for better error response (https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp/downloads). But you can use plain jQuery as well.

On the client side, you need something like this:

```
$.jsonp({
    "url": target_url+"ping.php?callback=?",
    "success": function(data) {
        // print out data
    },
    "error": function(d,msg) {
        // error
    }
});
```

The ping.php file on target server:

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . "{'response' : 'success'}" . ')';
?>
```

Comment: Note that the site at the specified URL has to support JSONP for this to work. The particular URL the OP specified (http://183.77.251.173:90/api/function/getprice.aspx?code=1301&length=3M) returns JSON, though the site may have some way to request JSONP.

Comment: @nnnnnn can you please update more clear details.i don't what is JSONP and same -orrigin policy

Comment: If you have access to the target server, you can try the example I'v added to my answer. If you do not have access to the server, you need to ask if they have support for JSONP, and then change your code accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

As others have said you're getting error 0 is because the site is unreachable.  Cross site issue is a reason.  Of course so is an incorrect URL.  If the URL you're trying to reach does work and is on a different domain than your site then yes you have a cross domain issue.

JSONP is going to be your only way to get it to work but there's drawbacks.  Have a look at this post on SO for detailed explanation:

[What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

There's also a link in the article to http://www.json.org/JSONRequest.html.  I haven't tried this so not sure if it works.

This should help you on your way.

Answer (score -3):

For cross-domain use `$.getJSON()`.

```
$.getJSON('http://183.77.251.173:90/api/function/getprice.aspx?code=1301&length=3M', function(data){
alert(data.results[0].address_components[0].long_name);
});
```

Comment: Yes, but something like that.

Comment: No not at all. Read the other answers to see why.